# How can I retrieve data from Firebase with search query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a from Firebase. I followed the directions in the Firebase developer examples. When I try and pull the data, it comes up as null. I'm trying to retrieve the Location attribute.

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.child("TourGuides").orderByChild("location").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
   .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, User.class)
   .build();
```

[image: Firebase Snapshot]

Comment: This is a similar answer I put before this. Might help you. Check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62868314/13685592

Comment: Your query runs on a `TourGuides` node, but your JSON has `TourGuiderInformation`. Since `TourGuides` doesn't exist in the JSON, you'll get no results. You'll want `mUserDatabase.child("TourGuiderInformation").orderByChild("location")...`

Comment: Thanks, but it seem not to return any result, a logged in user is the one perfoming this search do i need to add userId or Auth methods in my query?